# Quicktime Logo Display Whilst Loading Video Content

Tags: video, loading, quicktime, graphical-logo

We are currently building a HTML5 platform using VIDEOJS and have come up against an issue when using it on an ipad.

We have several videos loading in a sequence which can be played when an icon is selected. The platform works perfectly on a desktop but when viewing on an ipad there is a black flash with a quicktime logo signalling that the video is loading before being played.

Is there any known work around for this, can we customise or get rid of the quicktime logo at all? We have tried implementing the following code to push the video to the side before it loads fully but it is not bringing back the video for some reason, just the audio.

```
function bringbackvideo()
{
    $("video").css("-webkit-transform", "translateX(0)");
}

function hidevideo()
{
    $("video").css("-webkit-transform", "translateX(-2048px)");
}
```

This workaround seems outdated since the last ios update -

http://blog.millermedeiros.com/html5-video-issues-on-the-ipad-and-how-to-solve-them/

Comment: I would also like to know if any work around exists - I confirm that the hack above no longer works for me either.